# on the way forward

Tags: meaning

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/future-bleak-russias-cowed-opposition-155140138.html):

> "It all reflects on a very dangerous, chilling atmosphere for people who stood on the same side of the barricades as he did."
>   The outpouring of anger over Nemtsov's killing spurred some opposition figures to launch talks **on the way forward**, such as presenting common electoral lists for 2016 legislative polls.
>   "The chances of a union have increased after the assassination of Nemtsov," his friend Vladimir Milov told AFP, gloomily admitting that some opposition figures were seriously considering leaving the country.

How do you understand that phrase?

Comment: Think of *the way forward* as meaning *a [possible] solution*. They launched (started having) talks on (about) solving the problems that led to Nemtsov's killing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means "regarding a decision on which way to go forward."